# How to update cross object fields using trigger?

Tags: trigger

Could anyone please help me to update cross object fields

I have wrote one trigger but it won't working properly check it once and update it

actually i have taken one standard object `Case` and one custom object `CaseUser__c` base on case reason(picklist) field selection  it will update custom object field  called picklist(skill__c).

the custom object have some case user records in custom object with skill__c field is empty.

if we are create a new case with a case reason field selection it will assign related CaseUser record in custom object.

**Apex Trigger**

```
trigger updateCaseUser on Case (after insert, after update){

    List<ID> OppIds = New List<ID>();

    for(Case c : Trigger.new) {
        if(c.Reason == 'Other') {
          OppIds.add(c.Id); //add case ids.
        }
    }

    //based on caseIds retrieve related CaseUsers whose skills needs to be updated.
    List<CaseUser__c> cuser = [SELECT id, skill__c FROM CaseUser__c WHERE id in :OppIds];

    for (integer i = 0 ; i < cuser.size(); i++) {
        cuser[i].skill__c = 'It Team';
     }

    update cuser;  
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: I am assuming your *cuser* list is always empty?

Comment: this trigger is nothing effect to caseuser__c object (based on case reason picklist field how a CaseUser field skill__c(picklist) is updated )

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to filter *CaseUser__c* records from your `OppIds` list, which is a list of *Case* ids.  The current query will never return anything because *Case* and *CaseUser__c* are not the same object (their id prefixes are different).  You need to switch your WHERE filter to be the *CaseUser__c* object's custom *Case* lookup field instead of id:

```
List<CaseUser__c> cuser = [SELECT id, skill__c FROM CaseUser__c WHERE caseLookupField in :OppIds];
```

Comment: this trigger is nothing effect to caseuser__c object (based on case reason picklist field how a CaseUser field skill__c(picklist) is updated

Comment: only after update trigger is updated.please check it once